# How to change ADF sink dataset Parquet file datatypes in Azure ADF Pipelines

Tags: parquet, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse, polybase

I have created some ADF pipeline to copy multiple csv files and merge into single Parquet file and place in another storage account. After that I have created Polybase sql script to copy data from external table to SQL Pool database.

External table create query:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [dbo].[test]
(
    [Field1] VARCHAR(100) null,
    [Field2] VARCHAR(100) null,
    [Value] decimal(10,7) null,
    [Field4] VARCHAR(100) null
)
WITH
(
    LOCATION = '***',
    DATA_SOURCE = test_data_source,
    FILE_FORMAT = ParquetFileFormat
)
```

When I query for top 10 records:

```
select top 10 * from [dbo].[test]
```

getting below error:

```
HdfsBridge::recordReaderFillBuffer - Unexpected error encountered filling record reader buffer: HadoopUnexpectedException: Request failed due to an internal error that occurred during map-reduce job execution. Exception message = [Parquet column with primitive type [optional binary Value (UTF8)] cannot be converted to [DECIMAL] because parquet type is not annottated with decimal metadata].
```

If I convert field Value to varchar then it works.
Below screenshot from ADF Copy activity.

[image]

Sink Dataset has custom Schema fields:
[image]

I can not edit Destination Datatype in Parquet File.

How to solve this?

Comment: Does your Sink Dataset have a schema defined?

Comment: @JoelCochran Yes, I have added schema by importing small parquet file. Updated the screenshot, Please heck.

Answer (score 0):

You can `import schema` from a sample file instead of from storage.

In properties, you can mention to import schema **from sample file** and upload the schema file of required format.

[image]

You can also add the sample schema file in the sink dataset under schema by adding import schema from sample file browse the file.

[image]